# Angular 2: Add a class dynamically in ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a class dynamically inside ***ngFor**. When I enter invalid text in textbox, it will change the textbox border to red color.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let appt of appointments">
    <div class="ctrl-wpr" *ngIf="appt.personVitals && appt.personVitals.weight">
        <md-input class="ctrl-wpr__ctrl" [(ngModel)]="appt.personVitals.weight.weight" [ngClass]="{'error_bgcolor': errcolor }" (keyup)="validate(appt.personVitals.weight.weight)"
            (blur)="updatePersonvitals(appt.personVitals.weight, 'kgs', appt.patientInfo.id)">
        </md-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
validate(wt: any) {
        if (/^\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$/.test(wt)) {
            this.errcolor = false;
        }
        else {
            this.errcolor = true;
        }
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.error_bgcolor {
        .md-input-underline .md-input-ripple  {  
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
            transform: scaleY(1);
        }        
    }
```

The problem I have is when invalid text is entered, red color is applying to all textboxes, not just the one that is invalid. How can I make it more dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using one same value (value of variable `errcolor`) in all `ngClass` directives, so if one of the inputs is invalid, all of them are marked as invalid. You can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let appt of appointments">
    <div class="ctrl-wpr" *ngIf="appt.personVitals && appt.personVitals.weight">
        <md-input class="ctrl-wpr__ctrl" [(ngModel)]="appt.personVitals.weight.weight" [ngClass]="{'error_bgcolor': validate(appt.personVitals.weight.weight)}" (keyup)="validate(appt.personVitals.weight.weight)"
        (blur)="updatePersonvitals(appt.personVitals.weight, 'kgs', appt.patientInfo.id)">
        </md-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your validate method:

```
validate(wt: any) {
    if (/^\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$/.test(wt)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```